# Need apache regex config for rewrite rule

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Here is a scenario of what I am trying to do.

Folder A has folders B and C.
Folder B has D, E and index.html.
Folder C has index.html

I declared folder B as my DocumentRoot. Declared an Alias for Folder C to point it to /A/C. I want apache to serve index.html in B for any requests coming in to B (/B/D or /B/E  or /B/** should return /B/index.html)

Here is the sample  virtual host config

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
...
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/var/www/A/B" 
Alias "/C" "/usr/local/var/www/A/C" 
<Directory "/usr/local/var/www/A"> 
....
</Directory> 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200 
RewriteRule ^/B/.+ /B/ [PT] 
....
</VirtualHost>
```

With this configuration, I am running in to redirect loop.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/?test/.+ /test/ [NC,L]` should work

Comment: Thanks for the reply @anubhava. We don't want to use NC as we have other rules that should be processed. When I try the above rule with [PT] pass through flag, it runs in to recursion problem. .+ should check if one or more characters exist, but it somehow runs in to recursion.

Comment: Ok, add `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200` condition before `RewriteRule`

Comment: Can you add these details in questions by clicking on edit link below your questions

Comment: Thanks for the reply @anubhava. I updated question.  I can attach my sample httpd-vhosts.conf, if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this rule:

```bash
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200 
RewriteRule ^/?B/(?!index\.html$) /B/index.html [L,NC]
```

Then:

1. Restart your Apache
2. Test in a new browser or completely clear your browser cache

Comment: In the RewriteRule it must be redirected to /B/index.html instead of /B/ . I thought it would pick index.html by default. That did the trick. Thanks for being responsive and formatting the questions!!

Answer (score 0):

the original request path,"/test/c/1", will match with "^/test/[abc].+$", matched successfully, so the request path change from "test/c/1" to "/test/". but due to the PT flag, cause the  "/test/" routed back as if "/test/" is a newly come in, so "/test/" will match with "^/test/[abc].+$" again, but this time match failed, so you got 404.

change the flag from PT to L, the behavior is while the original request path,"/test/c/1", match with "^/test/[abc].+$" successfully, the redirected path "/path" will be the final path. apache get the resource related "/test/" and response to the client.